# JSF Data Retrieve from Database at page load

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I am new to Java Web Development and I came across a problem. I need to implement a system with JSF.
The problem: I need to create a menu that has the elements from my database. I see everywhere how to develop hello world applications with only 2 pages but these don't help me to develop that menu.
I am planning to use PrimeFaces 5 along with JSF 2.2 .
Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I guess it was not understandable so I am explaining it more clearly.

I need to implement a dynamic menu which retrieves it's data from a database with a query that has WHERE clause. 
For example, I am trying to get Categories from a database with user_id = *something*.
I can't use dataTable of primefaces directly.

In another aspect, I have problems with using managed beans.
I couldn't quite understand where and when should I retrieve the data from database.

Normally, I use JSP and I put necessary queries just before where I use them. However, in JSF I couldn't figure out when and where to use.

Comment: Your problem is way too general. If you have a specific problem while implementing your project, come back and ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://javaknowledge.info/display-datatable-from-mysql-db-in-primefaces/

best
vj

Comment: I updated the question. If you can re-check..